# What precedes the end of a Democratic Government?

Tags: democracy, history

Democracies allow people to participate equally, whether directly or indirectly, though there is a [significant level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_democracy) of variation in how they are implemented.

I expect that a democratic form of government would be negatively impacted by a lack of participation. Would this be the result of an abandonment of the social contract at the foundation of democratic governance? Is that indicative of a lack of interest or insufficient understanding?

I am concerned by the apparent disinterest I've observed, and have become curious if this occurred in other Democracies.

Comment: I mean a computer program is just a series of rules, and if you don't do checksums on those rules to make sure no hackers have changed them, then you have no idea that the rules have even changed, and even if you do know that the rules have changed you don't know which ones or in what way to find out what your program is doing; it seems to me that unlimited political campaign contribution is about the same thing as not checking your checksums.

Comment: When citizens don't participate in democratic processes, then campaign donations don't help either. A completely depoliticized citizen doesn't pay attention to campaign advertisement and won't vote anyway. Campaigning can only sway the opinion of those citizens who still have an interest in politics (but not enough to form their own opinion based on non-biased sources).

Comment: By the way, I'm not against Democracy, I'm worried about it.

Comment: Can you detail what you mean by "stupid" and "distracted"? And maybe how much of a change counts?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Do you watch TV?  Do you use the Internet?  It's so easy to get distracted now days it's ridiculous;  The candidates say stupid things to stay in the news; there's reality tv stars, there's the Olympics, there's facebook; it all seems a little too convenient...sure you can follow the Supreme Court on twitter, but how many people really follow it?  Maybe just a little over 100,000 people; this is not a populous that is interested in their own country.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Every day I turn on the news and it drops the IQ a little more than it did the day before...why?  To distract from what's really going on.

Comment: @leeand00 I'm pretty sure citizens of old Athens weren't so distracted by TV and Internet that they forgot to vote (also, it was compulsory). And I'm not even sure you'd find a correlation between the amount of time in front of TV and/or Internet and the voting rate.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin what about time spent working?

Comment: @leeand00 so you want to see examples of societies where the people were working so much that they did not turn up to vote? Do take your time to define your terms, and consider editing your question accordingly.

Comment: Examine your Premise; how many governments like the one built at the founding of these United States have existed? Are these United States a Democracy?

Comment: @DrunkCynic You're right, probably not.  It used to be.  But not anymore.

Comment: Looks like my question has again been foiled by the conservative police...

Comment: @leeand00 no, it was foiled by not properly defining the scope of the question. Follow the suggestions by bilbo_pingouin and Drunk Cynic and the question might get reopened. The only police around here is the bad question police.

Comment: @leeand00 Eh, no. Calling the crowd stupid and distracted establishes the derogatory tone of your question: rant. Unsupported claim that Citizens United allows foreign individuals to funnel money into campaign coffers: provide a citation. Question then redirects towards asking if these reason's are why monarchies were the dominate form of government: demonstrative of a strong misunderstanding of history. As one of the few open conservatives visiting this stack, I challenge you to do better.

Comment: I've voted for reopening, based on @DrunkCynic's heroic editing job.  I'm not sure this is still the same question as the OP asked, but it's now an answerable one that's appropriate for the site.  And it's close enough that it should elicit relevant answers.

Comment: @Bobson Wouldn't bother. The edit is more demonstrative of a well written question than an intent to get the question re-opened. Don't expect it to last long anyway.

Comment: "What precedes the end of a Democratic Government?" - *mumble* Sith *mumble* Taxation of Trade Routes *mumble* Chosen One *mumble* Midichlorians *mumble*

Comment: It is unclear, what constitutes the End of a Democracy here, namely, does he mean the overthrow by a different political system (which can occur quite irrespective of the developments mentioned), or des he mean the decline of the real value of democracy, which is such a gradual matter, that the answer becomes highly opinion based and circumstantial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you identify isn't really one of how government is selected but of the dangers of government having to much power over it's citizens. Really what is required are unambiguous legal protections for the rights and freedoms of citizens so no matter what the makeup and intentions of the government they cannot act, at least not within the law, as a tyranny. A well armed citizenry able to offer resistance can also help.

For example I am from the UK, right now we have people in our prisons that are there solely for tweeting unfashionable or 'tasteless' remarks. That couldn't happen in the US, although there are many that would like it to be otherwise, because your free speech is protected by law that the government cannot easily overturn.

Any system, institution or power could become co-opted, which is why they should always be very restrained and limited in the power they wield.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44107/discussion-on-answer-by-user1450877-what-precedes-the-end-of-a-democratic-govern).

Comment: Interesting, I never thought of it like that.